# How to remove duplicates from a list

Tags: java

I have a list that contain elements, I want to remove the duplicates. I have tried to do that but it didn't work.

This is the code :

```
//list is the original list containing duplicates
Iterator it1=list.iterator();//iterator1 
 while (it1.hasNext())
  {
    Iterator it2=list.iterator(); //iterator2
    if(it1.next().equals(it2.next()))
     {
       //liststeps is the list without duplicates
       liststeps.add(it1.next());
     }
  } 
System.out.println("multiple list  "+list.toString());
System.out.println("list  "+liststeps.toString());
```

**Results:**

```
multiple list  [Open, In Progress, Waiting Customer Test, Closed, Open, Step11, Step22,  Open, In Progress, Waiting Customer Test, Closed]
list  [In Progress, Step11, In Progress]
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need a list ? If not, as Tobiask suggested, you should use a set, that won't allow redundancies.

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the elements appear in the de-duplicated list?

Comment: If the order is relevant, use: http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply construct a [`HashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) from your list:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

This will remove the duplicates, but will likely re-order the elements. If you want to preserve the order in which the (unique) elements appear in the original list, use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

```
Set<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);
```

Lastly, if you need the output to be a list, convert the set to a list like so:

```
List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a List. You can use [addAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to add your list to the Set, then convert it back to a List or just use the Set. And if the order is relevant, use a [LinkedHashSet](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

And just a suggestion: use [for-each](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) instead of iterator... it´s easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `next` way to often, it always moves to the next element.

```
if(it1.next().equals(it2.next())) {
     liststeps.add(it1.next());
}
```

This code actually adds the next element after the one you compared to your list.

Use a Set/for-each as Tobiask pointed out.